# How to convert style text to C# object such as class/hashTable/collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, regex, c#-4.0

I have style text like this one:

```
".abc {border: 1px solid blue;color:black;...} 
.abc{background-image:url('http://example.com/images/a.png')...}
#abcd {color: blue}..."
```

I need to edit this text in the server (change background-image or add color property... ) and then save it as text.

I think the best way is to convert this text to a c# object such class/hashTable/collection ...

can some one help me with this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to keep as little style information in your C# code as possible.  It would be better to define different classes in your CSS files corresponding to different styles and then to deal only with class names server side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ....but it's a very complicated system and I have to do it this way

Answer (score 0):

Use the **`CssStyleCollection`** in-built class.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style style = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style(); 
// you can set various properties on style object.

CssStyleCollection cssStyleCollection = style.GetStyleAttributes(SOME_USER_CONTROL OR YOUR PAGE);
cssStyleCollection.Add("border", "1px solid blue"); // etc
```

The other option is to use the following structure:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> cssValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

cssValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>("abc", new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("border", "1px solid blue"),
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("color", "black"),
 // so on
}));
```

we use list of KeyValuePairs instead of dictionary, because CSS classes can repeat and there is no guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: Please, add some examples of usage. Your answer does not directly solve the problem of the OP as it stands now.

Comment: Hi raja,can you please write a samll sample code of how to convert the style text to collection/...  thanks